# How to change a file input's FileList programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this `input` of type `"file"`, and I want to change its `files` list.  Example:

```
<input type = "file" id = "fileinput" />
<script type = "text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("fileinput").files = [10];
</script>
```

The problem is that the `fileinput` element's `files` list is not set. How do I do it?

Comment: You can't. It's read only for obvious security reasons.

Comment: I see, so then I can't allow it to upload multiple files with multiple clicks then?

Comment: @dave HTML5 allow multiple selection of files but you still can't decide what will be those files.

Comment: I see.  So there is no way via javascript or scripting that I can alter the state of file input?

Comment: @dave you can alter anything but the selected file(s) of the control..

Comment: So could I alter fileinput.filelist?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For security reasons, browsers prevent javascript from changing the files which will be uploaded: only the user can select files via the user interface. This is to prevent an evil script to upload `/etc/passwd`, for example, without the user knowing.

The one exception is that calling "reset" on the form will clear the file or filelist, but you can never add to programmatically.

Comment: So how would i add more files to the file input's filelist when clicking it multiple times?

Comment: @odrm you can't add local *real* files to file list, but there's nothing wrong with adding `File` or `Blob`. I could imagine an userscript that would do that and be helpful.

Comment: @Tomáš Zato I don't think you could, because how the browser would know the origin of the file, if it is a programmatically created or stolen from the user?

Comment: @atas you cannot steal blob from the user programmatically unless they submit it already.

Comment: @TomášZato that was what I meant. You cannot add an arbitrary file you create yourself programatically (or retrieved from a server), which the user had not submitted.

Comment: @atas And what does that have to do with security? You could always override form's `onsubmit` event and create the request using AJAX.

Answer (score 55):

It's **indeed impossible** to **add a *local* file** to a file input that the user didn't request; however, **there is** a way to **add `Blob` or `File` objects** to or **remove specific files** from a file input.

---

To change the files in the file input, you have to replace the `fileInput.files` with another [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object.

The problem is that `FileList` objects are **immutable** and **have no constructor** exposed to JS.

The only way of creating custom `FileList`s is by abusing [`DataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer), an API designed for transferring files using drag-and-drop or through the clipboard.

It is supported in all mainstream browsers, but not in IE, and only since version 14.1 in Safari. You can check it [here](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_datatransfer_datatransfer).

You can create a `DataTransfer` object by invoking its constructor without arguments:

```js
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
```

The created `DataTransfer` object has a [`files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/files) property, which is, fortunately, a `FileList` containing all files the `DataTransfer` has.

But then how to add files to the `DataTransfer`?

Each `DataTransfer` has a [`DataTransferItemList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItemList) associated with it (accessible through its [`items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/items) property) that has the methods for adding (and removing) items to (and from) the `DataTransfer`.

To add a file, you have to call the [`add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItemList/add) method on it and pass a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object.

Like so:

```js
dataTransfer.items.add(file)
```

If you have data that is not in a `File` object (e.g. a `Blob` or `ArrayBuffer` of bytes), you can use the [`File` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File), passing the data, the filename, and optionally an object with `type` and `lastModified` properties to it:

```js
const file = new File([blob], 'file.txt', {type: 'text/plain', lastModified: modificationDate})
```

So, to sum up, we have something like this:

```
new DataTransfer()
 |
 v
DataTransfer 
 |  |
 |  +--[ .items ]---> DataTransferItemList
 |                      |
 +--[ .files ]------+   +---[ .add(file) ]---> DataTransferItem
                    |               ^
                    v               |
 +--[ .files ] <-- FileList         |
 |                                  +--- File <--- new File([data], filename, options)
 |                                                            ^
 |                                                            |
<input type="file">      Blob ----------+---------------------+
                         ArrayBuffer ---+
                         string --------+
```

I'm sure this is quite messy right now, but let's see some code!

If you wanted to create a file named `hello.txt` containing `Hello world!` and set the input to contain this file, here's how can you do it:

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput')

const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()

const file = new File(['Hello world!'], 'hello.txt', {type: 'text/plain'})

dataTransfer.items.add(file)

fileInput.files = dataTransfer.files
```

```html
<p>Notice that the file input contains "hello.txt" now: </p>
<input type="file" id="fileInput" />
```

But instead of replacing the files, how can you edit the list of files already in the input?

1. Create a `DataTransfer`
2. Add all existing files from the input except the ones you want to remove
3. Add the files you want to add
4. Replace the files in the input with the ones in the `DataTransfer`

See also [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66569361/8376184) about that topic.

For doing this, I've created a pair of functions for getting and setting the file list from an array of `File`s, so the transformations can be performed on arrays instead of doing complicated stuff with `DataTransfer`s:

```js
function getFiles(input){
  const files = new Array(input.files.length)
  for(let i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++)
    files[i] = input.files.item(i)
  return files
}

function setFiles(input, files){
  const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
  for(const file of files)
    dataTransfer.items.add(file)
  input.files = dataTransfer.files
}
```

You can use them like this:

```js
function getFiles(input){
  const files = new Array(input.files.length)
  for(let i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++)
    files[i] = input.files.item(i)
  return files
}

function setFiles(input, files){
  const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()
  for(const file of files)
    dataTransfer.items.add(file)
  input.files = dataTransfer.files
}

const fileInput = document.querySelector('#fileInput')

document.querySelector('#removeFirst').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const files = getFiles(fileInput)
  
  files.shift()
  
  setFiles(fileInput, files)
})
document.querySelector('#removeLastModified').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const files = getFiles(fileInput)
  
  let latest = 0, latestIndex
  for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    if(files[i].lastModified > latest){
      latest = files[i].lastModified
      latestIndex = i
    }
  files.splice(latestIndex, 1)  
  
  setFiles(fileInput, files)
})
document.querySelector('#addFile').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const files = getFiles(fileInput)
  
  const newFiles = getFiles(document.querySelector('#addFileInput'))
  files.push(...newFiles)
  
  setFiles(fileInput, files)
})
document.querySelector('#addRandomHello').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const files = getFiles(fileInput)
  
  const newFile = new File(['Hello world!'], 'hello.txt', {type: 'text/plain'})
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (files.length + 1))
  files.splice(index, 0, newFile)
  
  setFiles(fileInput, files)
})
```

```html
Hint: hover over the file input to see the list of all files in it <br>
<input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple ><br><br>
<button id="removeFirst">Remove first file</button><br>
<button id="removeLastModified">Remove latest modified file</button><br>
<button id="addFile">Append file from this input</button> <input type="file" id="addFileInput" /><br>
<button id="addRandomHello">Add a hello.txt file to a random place</button><br>
```

Comment: Take note of the bowser support on the [DataTransfer constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/DataTransfer) if you choose to use this answer.

Comment: @Manstie Well, yes, it's not supported in IE, but support seems fair otherwise. IE support is often dropped in present-day projects. Anyway, I'll mention that.

Comment: My main concern would be Safari >=14.1, eliminating support for old Macintosh systems where they can not upgrade.

Comment: None of this is a criticism to your answer, just warning people if they go to use it.

Comment: I got that, I'm just trying to add everything to my answer so that people don't have to read the comments to get this info.

Comment: That's an awesome workaround!

Comment: As of 2023 it still works, this should be noted as the right answer ! 
Also today with lot of people using typescript, your "getFiles()"  could be replaced using destructuring : [...input.files]

Comment: @camb I posted this as a late answer and the OP isn't active anymore, that's why it's not accepted. Regarding `[...input.files]`, that would also work in JS, but it requires `FileList` to be iterable, [which isn't specified by the HTML standard](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#filelist-section), so I chose to avoid it (although Chromium and FF both implement `FileList.prototype[@@iterator]`).

Comment: The actual conversion should be `Array.from(input.files)` which handles almost all edge cases which choke generators and is supported everywhere.

Comment: @BillerBuilder I changed it. I originally implemented it using the `item()` function because the WHATWG spec didn't specify that `FileList` has to support indexing (even though major browsers did implement it), and I decided to err on the safe side. Even now isn't it super clear, although now the spec includes a note saying that the `item()` syntax is being phased out.

Answer (score -2):

What you want is using the `multiple` attribute on the `input` element. That way, in newer browsers user will be able to select multiple files to upload.