# Javascript drag&drop wont work on Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Ive made a simple drag n drop feature in Javascript. It work very well but only on Opera, Safari or Chrome. But in Firefox and IE it wont. Please can anyone help me?

The main thing is that I need to assign the dropped file to a File Input.

The source code:

```
var file_drop = document.getElementById('...');


var dOver = function(evt) {
evt.stopPropagation();
evt.preventDefault();
evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
}

var dEnd = function(evt) {
...
}

var dLeave = function(evt) {
...
}

var dDrop = function(evt) {
evt.stopPropagation();
evt.preventDefault();
temp_file = evt.dataTransfer.files;
document.getElementById('file-select').files = temp_file;
}

file_drop.addEventListener('dragover', dOver, false);
file_drop.addEventListener('dragend', dEnd, false);
file_drop.addEventListener('dragleave', dLeave, false);
file_drop.addEventListener('drop', dDrop, false);
```

---

Anyone can help me? What do I wrong? :/

Comment: Open the developer console in IE (press F12). In there you most probably will see an error in your console tab, which will tell you that IE doesn't support a method your probably using in this code. If that is the case, you need to use an alternative way.

Comment: The console doesnt show any errors. Console log is clear :/

Comment: Could you prepare a https://jsfiddle.net/ in which we could reproduce that?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/y9yvkcco/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change the file input's filelist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632629/how-to-change-the-file-inputs-filelist)

Comment: Doesnt work :/ https://jsfiddle.net/y9yvkcco/19/