# Proper way to create a controlled `<input type='file'>` element in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

Most `<input>` elements use a `value` prop to set the value, and so they can be externally controlled by a parent.

However `<input type='file'>` sets its value from a `files` attribute, and I'm struggling to make that work correctly. `files` can not be set directly as a prop, but it can be set on the DOM directly via a ref, so I use `useEffect()` to accomplish this:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const FileInput = (props) => {
  const { value } = props;
  const inputRef = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (value === "") {
      inputRef.current.value = "";
    } else {
      inputRef.current.files = value;
    }
  }, [value]);
  
  return <input type="file" ref={inputRef} />;
};

export default FileInput;
```

I'd like to include an `onChange()` handler for when the user selects a file, but the `<FileList>` object is tied to the DOM and I get an error when trying to use it to set the `value`:

```
DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

I keep going in circles on the "right" way to write a controlled form input. Is there a way to set the `files` attribute and `value` attribute correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

First of all, we know from this [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html) question that we can't set the `value` property for `<input type='file'/>` element programmatically.

Secondly, we know from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68182158/6463558 answer that we can set the `files` property via [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer).

So the `FileInput` component could be:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import * as React from 'react';

export type FileInputProps = {
  fileList: File[];
  onChange(fileList: FileList): void;
};
const FileInput = ({ fileList = [], onChange }: FileInputProps) => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
      fileList.forEach((file) => dataTransfer.items.add(file));
      inputRef.current.files = dataTransfer.files;
    }
  }, [fileList]);

  return (
    <input
      type="file"
      ref={inputRef}
      data-testid="uploader"
      onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        onChange(e.target.files);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default FileInput;
```

For a live demo, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-b7gfhv?file=FileInput.tsx)